# Modify ViewModel property value through Javascript in MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

Is it possible to change a property value from a ViewModel using javascript?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @Model.PageNumber = 2;
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe if you try to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish we might be able to help.

Comment: I managed doing this the other way, thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JavaScript is on the client-side(unless you are using Node.js), and MVC3 Views are rendered on the server-side in the Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

No; that page code is executed once; changing the model wouldn't do anything even if it was allowed.

If you want a view model that can change on the client-side, and have the UI automatically update in response to changes, [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com) is what you're looking for. With KnockoutJS, you can have view models with properties that can be changed in javascript, and the UI will automatically update accordingly.